# What is the android.widget.Toast equivalent for iOS applications?

Tags: ios, toast

I have made Android application a few months ago. The Toast class is very useful for me. 
I do not need to consider the main Thread and place to show it. Anywhere I can show it and just leave that and it is automatically disappeared.

```
Toast.makeToast(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

That's it. ^^

What about iPhone? Is there something like the Toast? Just show message and do not need to care about it. It will be automatically disappeared.

Comment: considering that only with iOS 4 allowed background apps, there was no previous need for such a feature.  No doubt someone will make one, but I'm not familiar with anything like it.

Comment: @StephenFurlani, although it's not obvious immediately, toast messages are also useful, and widely used, in foreground apps.

Comment: @DanielS. I whole-heartedly agree.  However, the OP is almost 4 years old.  At this point there are some GREAT features w/ iOS 8 regarding `UIPopoverPresentationController`s and `passthroughViews`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no class "out-of-the-box" in UIKit to do this. But it is quite easy to create a class that will offer this behavior.

You just have to create a class that inherit from UIView. This class will have the responsibility
 - to create what you want to display,
 - to add itself in parent view hierarchy
 - to dismiss itself using a timer.

You will be able to use it like :

```
[ToastView toastViewInView:myParentView withText:@"what a wonderful text"];
```

Regards,
Quentin

Comment: No code example? You have only suggested an API for a toast should work.

Comment: I have a better solution, just code something like: import ProjectGenerator miracle.insertFinishedProject()  ...it should work.

Comment: You can find a code sample below in this thread. Thanks @Scarmysun

Comment: @Josh, that is no good unless you call the DoWhatIMean procedure...repeatedly.

Answer (score 72):

I've been writing for Android for a long time and I am missing Toast. I've implemented one. Need code? here you are:

**ToastView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ToastView : UIView

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *text;

+ (void)showToastInParentView: (UIView *)parentView withText:(NSString *)text withDuaration:(float)duration;

@end
```

**ToastView.m**

```
#import "ToastView.h"

@interface ToastView ()
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) UILabel *textLabel;
@end
@implementation ToastView
@synthesize textLabel = _textLabel;

float const ToastHeight = 50.0f;
float const ToastGap = 10.0f;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

-(UILabel *)textLabel
{
    if (!_textLabel) {
        _textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, 5.0, self.frame.size.width - 10.0, self.frame.size.height - 10.0)];
        _textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        _textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        _textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
        _textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0];
        _textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
        [self addSubview:_textLabel];

    }
    return _textLabel;
}

- (void)setText:(NSString *)text
{
    _text = text;
    self.textLabel.text = text;
}

+ (void)showToastInParentView: (UIView *)parentView withText:(NSString *)text withDuaration:(float)duration;
{

    //Count toast views are already showing on parent. Made to show several toasts one above another
    int toastsAlreadyInParent = 0;
    for (UIView *subView in [parentView subviews]) {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[ToastView class]])
        {
            toastsAlreadyInParent++;
        }
    }

    CGRect parentFrame = parentView.frame;

    float yOrigin = parentFrame.size.height - (70.0 + ToastHeight * toastsAlreadyInParent + ToastGap * toastsAlreadyInParent);

    CGRect selfFrame = CGRectMake(parentFrame.origin.x + 20.0, yOrigin, parentFrame.size.width - 40.0, ToastHeight);
    ToastView *toast = [[ToastView alloc] initWithFrame:selfFrame];

    toast.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    toast.alpha = 0.0f;
    toast.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;
    toast.text = text;

    [parentView addSubview:toast];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        toast.alpha = 0.9f;
        toast.textLabel.alpha = 0.9f;
    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if(finished){

        }
    }];


    [toast performSelector:@selector(hideSelf) withObject:nil afterDelay:duration];

}

- (void)hideSelf
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        self.alpha = 0.0;
        self.textLabel.alpha = 0.0;
    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if(finished){
            [self removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }];
}

@end
```

**Call from ViewController**

```
 [ToastView showToastInParentView:self.view withText:@"What a toast!" withDuaration:5.0];
```

Comment: Great (@Scarmysun: except for the extra colon before the implementation body. SO won't let me do an edit that short, otherwise I'd have fixed it.. ). Upvoted

Comment: This crashed for me until I renamed "setTextLabel:" to something else. "setTextLabel:" gets called automatically any time the property is updated (since a property is just shorthand for using the getter or setter). After I made that change, it worked well.

Comment: Nice comment @BeccaP . I've updated my implementation. Now text label is private property and instantiated lazily. Added a "text" public property.

Comment: I had to change int toastsAlreadyInParent = 0; to 1 or else I had to call it twice before it would display.

Comment: This is a nice little object. Well done. Note that when setting the `ToastView` frame, you need to do that using the parent view's `bounds`, not `frame`. So this line: `CGRect parentFrame = parentView.frame;` should be `CGRect parentFrame = parentView.bounds;`. You won't see this error unless you have a parent view with a non-zero frame origin.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: Updated for Swift 3**

Here is a Swift 3 version based on wojciech_maciejewski's answer. This looks more like Android Toast and doesn't stack toasts on each other. It draws toast into the center of the screen. It can handle long multiline texts.

```
import UIKit

class ToastView: UIView {

    private static let hLabelGap: CGFloat = 40.0
    private static let vLabelGap: CGFloat = 20.0
    private static let hToastGap: CGFloat = 20.0
    private static let vToastGap: CGFloat = 10.0

    private var textLabel: UILabel!

    static func showInParent(_ parentView: UIView, _ text: String, duration: Double = 3.0) {
        let labelFrame = CGRect(x: parentView.frame.origin.x + hLabelGap,
                                y: parentView.frame.origin.y + vLabelGap,
                                width: parentView.frame.width - 2 * hLabelGap,
                                height: parentView.frame.height - 2 * vLabelGap)
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)
        label.text = text
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.frame = labelFrame
        label.sizeToFit()

        let toast = ToastView()
        toast.textLabel = label
        toast.addSubview(label)
        toast.frame = CGRect(x: label.frame.origin.x - hToastGap,
                             y: label.frame.origin.y - vToastGap,
                             width: label.frame.width + 2 * hToastGap,
                             height: label.frame.height + 2 * vToastGap)
        toast.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        toast.alpha = 0.0
        toast.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
        toast.center = parentView.center
        label.center = CGPoint(x: toast.frame.size.width / 2, y: toast.frame.size.height / 2)

        parentView.addSubview(toast)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
            toast.alpha = 0.9
            label.alpha = 0.9
        })

        toast.perform(#selector(hideSelf), with: nil, afterDelay: duration)
    }

    @objc private func hideSelf() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
            self.alpha = 0.0
            self.textLabel.alpha = 0.0
            }, completion: { t in self.removeFromSuperview() })
    }
}
```

Usage from another controller:

```
ToastView.showInParent(navigationController!.view, "Hello world")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in many ways one of the way is using `UIAlertViewController()` in `swift3`

```
let alertManager=UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Welcome!", preferredStyle: .alert)

self.present(alertManager, animated: true, completion: nil)

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now()+1,
 execute: {
                                    alertManager.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

                                })
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting swift version of Scarmysun answer:) many thanks

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ToastView: UIView {
    static let toastHeight:CGFloat = 50.0
    static let toastGap:CGFloat = 10;
    lazy var textLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(5.0, 5.0, self.frame.size.width - 10.0, self.frame.size.height - 10.0))


    static func showInParent(parentView: UIView!, withText text: String, forDuration duration: double_t) {

        //Count toast views are already showing on parent. Made to show several toasts one above another
        var toastsAlreadyInParent = 0;

        for view in parentView.subviews {
            if (view.isKindOfClass(ToastView)) {
                toastsAlreadyInParent++
            }
        }

        var parentFrame = parentView.frame;

        var yOrigin = parentFrame.size.height - getDouble(toastsAlreadyInParent)

        var selfFrame = CGRectMake(parentFrame.origin.x + 20.0, yOrigin, parentFrame.size.width - 40.0, toastHeight);
        var toast = ToastView(frame: selfFrame)

        toast.textLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        toast.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        toast.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        toast.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2
        toast.textLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13.0)
        toast.addSubview(toast.textLabel)

        toast.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        toast.alpha = 0.0;
        toast.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;
        toast.textLabel.text = text;

        parentView.addSubview(toast)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
            toast.alpha = 0.9
            toast.textLabel.alpha = 0.9
        })


        toast.performSelector(Selector("hideSelf"), withObject: nil, afterDelay: duration)

    }

    static private func getDouble(toastsAlreadyInParent : Int) -> CGFloat {
        return (70.0 + toastHeight * CGFloat(toastsAlreadyInParent) + toastGap * CGFloat(toastsAlreadyInParent));
    }

     func hideSelf() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: {
            self.alpha = 0.0
            self.textLabel.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: { t in self.removeFromSuperview() })
    }

}
```