# UIAlertView Button Action

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can I use two actions for `UIButton` click?I have a UIAlertView showing with two button.Play again and exit.Now i want to execute two method in the click event of these buttons.

Comment: Please create a bit more context, your question contains the word UIAlertView and the description doesn't hint how that fits in.

Comment: i have updated the question.please check it now.and tell me how can i do this?

Comment: i couldn't solve the problem yes...can you help me?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

### UPDATE - May 2016

UIAlertView is deprecated. You can now use UIAlertController as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32690371/640731).

### Old Answer with UIAlertView

1. You can create a UIAlertView like this

   ```
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Really reset?" 
                             message:@"Do you really want to reset this game?" 
                             delegate:self 
                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                             otherButtonTitles:@"reset", nil];

   [alert show];
   ```
2. To handle AlertView button click, you have to
   **conform to** `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol.

   ```
   @interface YourViewController:UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate>{
     .......
     .......
   }
   ```
3. Then **implement** `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol methods,

   ```
   - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView 
                      clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
       if (buttonIndex == [alertView cancelButtonIndex]){
         //cancel clicked ...do your action
       }else{
         //reset clicked
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: where should i put this funciton :      - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        //cancel clicked ...do your action
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        //reset clicked
    }
}

Comment: Be sure to conform to the UIAlertViewDelegate protocol.

Comment: oops yes..do one thing too, in the .h file of your controller confirm to UIAlertViewProtocol, ie if your controller name is SomeController in the .h file when we declare @interface SomeController:UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate>

Comment: my .h file starting like this already : how can i use another delegate here?@interface GameTableView : UITableViewController

Comment: thank you so much...finally i made your suggestion working....credit goes to you.....have a coffee by my name...:)

Comment: Is there a constant defined for cancel button? It would be great instead of 0 check.

Comment: [alertView cancelButtonIndex]

Comment: @RahulHawge No longer dabbles in iOS, so bit slow. Thanks for the pointer. Just updated the answer to mention about deprecation.