# Alternative to UIAlertView for iOS 9?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, uialertview, uialertcontroller

`UAlertView` is deprecated in iOS 9 and later. What would be an alternative?

```
UIAlertView *new = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Your InApp Purchases were successfully restored" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[new show];
```

Comment: Any reason you didn't simply looks at the docs for `UIAlertView` (which tells you exactly what to do) or do a search before posting this question? Please make some attempt to find an answer before posting.

Comment: if you don't find answer in their doc, better shift your project to iOS 8. :P

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use this code to replace an alert view:

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];           
[alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If you need multiple actions you can use:

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
[alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Button 1" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    // action 1
}]];
[alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Button 2" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    // action 2
}]];
[alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}]];           
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: This takes so much code to implement... What are they thinking? The ability to handle responses without a delegate is a nice addition though.

Comment: @Kundapra Hudga, why did you choose to use dispatch_async for [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil]; ?

Comment: You are use the UIAlertController, See for Swift AlertController tutorial : https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/03/uialertcontroller-in-swift.html

Comment: Why presentViewController is called from dispatch queue?

Answer (score 9):

You get often detailed information including the replacement suggestion by <kbd>⌘</kbd>-clicking on the symbol which displays the class/method declaration.

In case of `UIAlertView` you will see

> "UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead"

Answer (score 3):

```
  UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                             alertControllerWithTitle:@"Info"
                             message:@"You are using UIAlertController"
                               preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

   UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                    actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                    style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                    {
                        [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                    }];
  UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                         actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                       handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                       {
                           [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                        }];
 [alert addAction:ok];
 [alert addAction:cancel];

 [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

I made a category for that:

```
+ (void)alertViewWithTitle:(NSString *)aTitle message:(NSString *)aMessage viewController:(UIViewController *) aVC
{
    UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController
                                 alertControllerWithTitle:aTitle ? aTitle : @""
                                 message:aMessage
                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIViewController *topVC = aVC ? aVC : [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
    [topVC presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The parameters `aTitle` and `aVC` are optional but `aVC` should be used if known.

PS: avoid the "new" as a variable name this is a reserved word, I actually don't know if it will compile though.

Answer (score 1):

[UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/) has been around since iOS 8.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                    alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Title"
                                    message:@"Enter User Credentials"
                                    preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

I have use "UIAlertController" on iOS 8 and later. Let see:

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Your InApp Purchases were successfully restored" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
```

And add buttons:

```
UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
           //do something when click button
}];
```

Remember:

```
[alertController addAction:okAction];
```

Then show it:

```
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nill];
```

If you want to show a actionsheep, you change

```
"preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet"
```