# how to navigate a view controller after pressing UIAlert button

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two screens. From first screen to next screen I was connect `push` segue in storyboard. Now in my second screen one alert will show with ok button. after pressing ok button i  need to go to my first screen

Here is my code:

```
- (void)signup:(NSDictionary *)params {
    if (error)
    {
        [PCUtilities showAlertWithTitle:@"Oops" message:error.localizedDescription cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"];
    }
}
```

Inside one method I have `UIAlert`.

This below code I tried but not working!!

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"ok"])
    {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AppMainNavController"] animated:YES];
    }
}
```

`AppMainNavController`  =  is my navigation controller story board id

Comment: `alertView` is deprecated now please use `UIAlertController` as mentioned here : [UIAlertView first deprecated IOS 9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32690086/uialertview-first-deprecated-ios-9)

Comment: Use button index instead comparing the strings (titles).

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if  (buttonIndex==0)
    {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pop to previous view controller as below. It will pop to Previous View controller which u have pushed from.

```
        - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
        {
            NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
            if([title isEqualToString:@"ok"])
            {
                [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            }
        }
```

Comment: U need to set delegate:self for UIAlertView inside method and also add UIALertViewDelegate to ur .h file

Comment: did't get you?? i added `uialertdelegate` in my .h.. And what to set delegate inside my ` - (void)signup:(NSDictionary *)params {` method   ??/

Comment: change as  delegate:self instead of delegate:nil at ur alert view code inside method.

Answer (score 0):

Use Button index instead of button title it will be difficult if the app has multiple languages. If you are using push segue then just dismiss current view controller, it will automatically go previous page weather there is Push segue or modal segue.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: still in my second view..not going back to my first view...i am using `show(e.g push) ` segue

Comment: no still it in my second view controller.. not going back

Comment: story board file means.. i dont have much point to update image??

Comment: i have one one main screen and second screen both are connected to one navigation controller. from my first to second view controller it wil go by seguge like `show(eg. push)