# MFMailComposeViewController is dismissing immediately when appear

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

The MFMailComposeViewController is dismissing immediately when appear

```
- (IBAction)btnContactPressed:(id)sender
{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailer setSubject:@"Feedback"];

        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"salimullah240@gmail.com", nil];
        [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];

        [self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:nil];
    } 
    else    
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failure"
                                                        message:@"Your device doesn't support the composer sheet"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled: you cancelled the operation and no email message was queued.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved: you saved the email message in the drafts folder.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail send: the email message is queued in the outbox. It is ready to send.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail failed: the email message was not saved or queued, possibly due to an error.");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Mail not sent.");
            break;
    }

    // Remove the mail view
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: you test in simulator?

Comment: Are you testing in Simulator or device?

Comment: Check in device may be it will work

Comment: There's a bug on simulator since iOS 8 that breaks this, device should work properly

Comment: Are you sure you are not calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. I tried and worked fine. The `MFMailComposeViewController` component can't be tested in the `iOS simulator` only in a `device`.

If you look this [Thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4415) in `Apple Developer Forums` the problem has a ticket in `Apple Bug Report` but still without any fix.

Also, just make sure you are importing:

```
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>
```

and adding the `delegate`:

```
@interface ViewController () <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

Comment: A extra tip to your code is: `UIAlertView` is deprecated. Use `UIAlertController` [see more](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32690371/4850561).