# Xamarin iOS WKWebView showing JavaScript Alert

Tags: javascript, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

I would like to show the JavaScript Alert in my WKWebView. I have implemented the IWKUIDelegate and its methods RunJavaScriptAlertPanel, RunJavaScriptConfirmPanel. These gets called for a JavaScript Alert. I would like to know how to handle the buttons and action on those buttons.

Is there a way i can write a generic UIAlertView for all JavaScript Alerts. For example below i have added errorAlert.AddButton("OK"); but in reality i don't know number of buttons and button title. Also how to handle the  completionHandler action

```
    [Export ("webView:runJavaScriptConfirmPanelWithMessage:initiatedByFrame:completionHandler:")]
    public void RunJavaScriptConfirmPanel (WKWebView webView, String message, WKFrameInfo frame,  Action<bool> completionHandler)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("RunJavaScriptConfirmPanel");


        UIAlertView errorAlert = new UIAlertView();
        errorAlert.Title = "Alert";
        errorAlert.Message = message;
        errorAlert.AddButton("OK");
        errorAlert.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure where you're trying to handle the action, whether it is in javascript or with C# in the app, so I'll try to address both. The short answer is, let javascript handle it, and if need be, make a call back to the app from javascript once a selection has been made from the dialog.

**Alert Example**

```
    public override void RunJavaScriptAlertPanel(WKWebView webView, string message, WKFrameInfo frame, Action completionHandler)
    {
        var alert = UIAlertController.Create("Alert", message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
        alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));

        //Let javascript handle the OK click by passing the completionHandler to the controller
        ViewController.PresentViewController(alert, true, completionHandler);
    }
```

**Confirm Example**

```
    public override void RunJavaScriptConfirmPanel(WKWebView webView, string message, WKFrameInfo frame, Action<bool> completionHandler)
    {
        var alert = UIAlertController.Create("Please confirm", message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

        //Let javascript handle the OK click by passing the completionHandler to the controller
        alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, action => completionHandler(true)));
        //Let javascript handle the Cancel click by passing the completionHandler to the controller
        alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Cancel", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, action => completionHandler(false)));

        ViewController.PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
    }
```

**Prompt Example**

```
    public override void RunJavaScriptTextInputPanel(WKWebView webView, string prompt, string defaultText, WKFrameInfo frame, Action<string> completionHandler)
    {
        var alert = UIAlertController.Create("Prompt", prompt, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
        alert.AddTextField(textfield => { textfield.Placeholder = defaultText; });
        alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, action => completionHandler(alert.TextFields[0].Text)));
        alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("Cancel", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, action => completionHandler(null)));
        ViewController.PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
    }
```

So that gives you an example of how to pass the button clicks back to javascript. If you want javascript to make a call back, you'll need to register script handlers by subclassing from `WKScriptMessageHandler`. There's a basic example here https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/41777/wkwebview-caching-not-working

Just as a note, `UIAlertView` has been deprecated. You might want to start using `UIAlertController` instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32690371/5606840. If you want access to the view controller to display the alerts, pass it into your `WKUIDelegate` class  at initialization.

*Edit*

To expand on how to handle the results in javascript

```js
alert('This is an alert');
```

The webview will pause the javascript thread and call `RunJavaScriptAlertPanel`. Once the OK button has been clicked, it will call back the completionHandler in the webview and the rest of the javascript code will execute.

```js
if (confirm('Do you want to confirm this?')) {
    //Do some code here when the user clicks ok
} else {
    //Do other code here when the user clicks cancel
}
```

As with the alert example, when javascript comes across the confirm method, it will call `RunJavaScriptConfirmPanel`. You can then show the dialog with the text passed through the message, along with an OK and Cancel button. Depending on the button clicked, the method will push either a true or false back to the webview and allow the rest of the javascript code to execute via the completion handler.

Comment: The problem with WKWebView is that it does not show JavaScript Alert directly. I need to add above methods to show the Alert in the app. Not sure what you mean by ---- The short answer is, let javascript handle it

Comment: Also i don't know how many buttons each Alert has and the button title. So i can't hardcode it as you shown above. Somehow i need to get that information from the these functions or JavaScript

Comment: An alert will only have one button, a Confirm will have buttons (ok & cancel), and a prompt will also only have 2 buttons along with a textbox. The examples above pretty much recreate the dialogs as would expect them to appear in a browser using native ui controls. Once a user clicks one of the buttons, the appropriate response will then be passed backed to the handlers in the webview.