# WKWebView gives exception Thread 1: signal SIGABRT while using location

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I have implemented WKWebView in my App. I want to show a website in it which uses the location like https://www.google.com/maps.

I have added the required location usage key-value pair in info.plist.

When I first open the app there is a prompt which asks for the location.

When I click Allow the app crashes with the Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error.

This works fine when I open URL in safari.

I am using the latest iOS/XCode version.

This is the error what I am getting.

```
LocationDemo[6299:420581] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectNotAvailableException', reason: 'UIAlertView is deprecated and unavailable for UIScene based applications, please use UIAlertController!'
```

Comment: Post the error message.

Comment: Please share your code which has an error for better explanation.

Comment: @emrcftci
I have added the error above, and I also get the answer for it.

An error was due to UIAertView is deprecated and unavailable for UIScene based applications. 
So as a part of a solution to this, I have removed UIScene as per described in this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58188069/uialertview-is-deprecated-and-unavailable-for-uiscene-based-applications-please