# WKWebview - IOS 13 : App is not detecting location?

Tags: xcode, geolocation, progressive-web-apps, wkwebview, ios13

I am using WKwebview for my PWA website which do ask for location access by using HTML5 Geolocation APIs. Everything is working fine in WKwebview, media is accessible, JS is working, But my app is not detecting location even not asking for location permission.

I then googled for answers and got few lines to add in info.plist, ie

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your location is required for xyz benefits for you</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your location is required for xyz benefits for you</string>
```

but even after adding this, it just asked for permission while failed to detect location and thrown error "Signal SIGBRT". How can i let my WKwebview app to send location to my PWA website ?

Comment: Maybe this can help you this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58418644, that work for me with same problem

Comment: This do worked for me too, thanks