# How to create a small popup in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, popup

I'm looking for the simplest code in order to implement a small popup (NOT a full screen modal popup or alert view). I just need it to display some basic text inside the popup, then exit it when I click away. The popup in the EleMints app is a good example.

[image: like this]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UIPopoverController does this, but it's limited to iPad only.  If you need this on iPhone, just implement a custom UIView subclass.  Then when you want to show your popover, instantiate the subclass and add it to your view, maybe with some animation.

Comment: Beginning with iOS 8, you can use `UIPopoverPresentationController` for iPhones and iPads. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32295641/3681880) for some links.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [WEPopOver](https://github.com/PaulSolt/WEPopover) as that is the one you required. For more info, visit this [link](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/open-source/ios-open-source-popover-api-for-iphone-wepopover.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the following refrence link for UIPopOver controller

1) [WEPopOver Library](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/open-source/ios-open-source-popover-api-for-iphone-wepopover.html)
2) [Popup Bubbles](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/open-source/ios-open-source-popup-bubbles-tips.html)