# iOS Dialog Box not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile, alert

I am trying to create a dialog box in my iOS app (app is a PhoneGap application).

I am using the code from this post: [how to implement a pop up dialog box in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988564/how-to-implement-a-pop-up-dialog-box-in-ios)

Below is the code that is in the link

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No network connection" 
                                                message:@"You must be connected to the internet to use this app."
                                               delegate:nil 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

I have put this code in `AppDelegate.m` in the method

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication)...`

The app runs but the dialog box does not show up.

What is the problem?

---

I have updated the code as below

The code below is in my appdelegate.m

```
//reachability code

if (networkStatus == ReachableViaWifi)
{
    while (true)
        //show progress bar
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"cancel", nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

The alert box is not showing up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: from which method of application you are showing AlertView? show your complete code.

Comment: @nsgulliver isn't application the method?

Comment: AppDelegate is implementing a protocol  called [UIApplicationDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), this delegate has many methods you can see in your delegate. they start with **application**

Comment: Here is the full line -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishWithOptions:(NSDDictionary*)launchOptions

Comment: I have mentioned in my answer down, you could have a look on explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can show the UIAlertView in the AppDelegate if you have done everything right, **but you can not exit the application using `exit()` method, it is not right practice in iOS to exit the app yourself**. Basically your AppDelegate is implementing [UIApplicationDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol, this protocol has many methods.

Try to show your AlertView in  different methods in your AppDelegate.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"cancel", nil];
    [alert show];

    // other code... 
}
```

OR in

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

   UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"cancel", nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Similarly you can show the alertview accordingly on your status change for the Reachability as you mentioned in the question.

Comment: What you mean by first sample is not working?  second is working? try to move it after initializing the window.

Comment: I never tried the second example. When I say the first sample is not working I meant that nothing happens. The alert box does not show up.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that is because your code is above the line `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`.

Try to move your code for alert after that line.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the code into your MainViewController.m (or other UIViewController .m file), and depending what behaviour you want the code should be added into `-(void)viewDidLoad` or `-(void)viewDidAppear` methods.

Comment: I want to be able to call the dialog in my appdelegate actually so how would I do that. From you answer what I understood was that I would put the UIAlerView *alert = ..... code in the -(void)viewDidLoad or -(void)viewDidAppear methods and I would call the dialog in my app delegate using [alert show];. Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: You can add the UIAlertView code inside the method: `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`. From what I read in your comments you added the code inside `-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application` this method is used for early version of iOS for iOS 3.0+ you should use the first method.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS alert dialog, in your AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No network connection" 
                                          message:@"You must be connected to the internet to use this app."
                                          delegate:nil 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Since you mentioned you are using phonegap, they will handle the alert box for you on different platforms. You would use the following code in one of your pages html

```
function showAlert() {
    navigator.notification.alert(
        'You must be connected to the internet to use this app.',
        null,       
        'No network connection',            
        'OK'                  
    );
}
```

Comment: Actually I want to call this alert box in my app delegate.m how would I do this?

Comment: Changed the post to run in appdelegate