# How do I make my app confirm that the user wants to delete something using one of those notification boxes?

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

This is probably a very simple question, but here it is:  how do I make it so that when a user taps "Discard" (in the navigation bar) a little box pops up that makes him confirm that he wants to discard what he's working on?  I would like it to look like that notification box that tells you you're out of storage in the built in camera app, but instead, have it say something like "Are you sure you want to discard this layout?" and then have one button be "yes" and the other be "no".  What is the code for doing this?  I am using Swift.

Comment: You should google `UIAlertView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `UIAlertController`. Here's a example:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title Text",
                                           message: "Message Text",
                                    preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK",
                                    style: .default,
                                  handler: { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
     //do your action here
})
alertController.addAction(okButton)

let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
    })
alertController.addAction(cancelButton)

self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

Comment: Thanks.  How do I add an unwind segue for the "ok" action?  Also, what is the code?  Specifically, I have a view between the current one and the one I want to unwind to.  I've been playing with it for an hour and I can't figure it out.  Thanks.

Comment: @W.Cook, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022479/how-would-i-create-a-uialertview-in-swift/33340757#33340757) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988564/how-to-implement-a-pop-up-dialog-box-in-ios). You don't have an unwind segue with an alert controller. You have a handler action function that is run with the user clicks on of the buttons.

Comment: @Suragch  So can I make my handler action function take the user back to a previous screen?  If so, how?  Thanks.

Comment: @Suragch I got it!  I called performSegueWithIdentifier, and that works.  Thanks.

Comment: @W.Cook, Ah, I didn't understand what you meant. I'm glad you figured it out.