# Displaying a message in iOS which has the same functionality as Toast in Android

Tags: android, ios

I need to know if there is any method in iOS which behaves like Toast messages in Android. That is, I need to display a message which is dismissed automatically after few seconds.  This is similar to the functionality of the Toast class in the Android environment.

Comment: You might want to check this link


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522866/android-toast-in-iphone

Comment: You can check this https://github.com/ecstasy2/toast-notifications-ios

Comment: This guy has provided the solution

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522866/what-is-the-android-widget-toast-equivalent-for-ios-applications

Comment: A nice lib: https://github.com/scalessec/Toast-Swift

Comment: The library that @FerranMaylinch recommended has the best results imho

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You can make use of [`MBProgressHUD`](https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD) project.

Use HUD mode `MBProgressHUDModeText` for toast-like behaviour,

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.navigationController.view animated:YES];

// Configure for text only and offset down
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeText;
hud.label.text = @"Some message...";
hud.margin = 10.f;
hud.yOffset = 150.f;
hud.removeFromSuperViewOnHide = YES;

[hud hideAnimated:YES afterDelay:3];
```

[image]

Comment: For 100% Android-like behaviour I suggest setting `hud.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` so you can interact with the rest of the app while the message is showing.

Comment: @MattiaC. I am not able to set value for `hud.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` looks like only getter is provided.

Comment: it's blocking UI. it's not the same behaviour as Android's one

Comment: Use `hud.offset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: MBProgressMaxOffset)` to position the HUD on the bottom edge.

Answer (score 97):

```
NSString *message = @"Some message...";

UIAlertView *toast = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                message:message
                                               delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[toast show];
        
int duration = 1; // duration in seconds
        
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, duration * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [toast dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
});
```

**Using UIAlertViewController for iOS 9 or later**

```
NSString *message = @"Some message...";

UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                                               message:message
                                                        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

int duration = 1; // duration in seconds

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, duration * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

**Swift 3.2**

```
let message = "Some message..."
let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
self.present(alert, animated: true)
    
// duration in seconds
let duration: Double = 5
    
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + duration) {
    alert.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly the same as toast - user interaction with other views is disabled while dialog is showing. Maybe there is a way to remove 'grayed out' background with adding ability to interact with other views on screen (like buttons or painting canvas in my case behind the alert)?

Comment: UIAlertView has been deprecated in iOS9. Is there any alternate way to do this?

Comment: thanks but could I use the UIAlertController to display the toast as well?

Answer (score 57):

In Android, a [Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) is a short message that displays on the screen for a short amount of time and then disappears automatically without disrupting user interaction with the app.

[image]

So a lot of people coming from an Android background want to know what the iOS version of a Toast is. Besides the current question, other similar questions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522866/what-is-the-android-widget-toast-equivalent-for-ios-applications), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221169/android-toast-in-iphone), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24893788/android-toast-equivalent-in-ios). The answer is that **there is no exact equivalent to a Toast in iOS**. Various workarounds that have been presented, though, including

- making your own Toast with a `UIView` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24894394/3681880), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3529135/3681880), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20904416/3681880), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4989839/3681880))
- importing a third party project that mimics a Toast (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27973876/3681880), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28365755/3681880), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24894988/3681880), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18740588/3681880))
- using a buttonless Alert with a timer (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23609624/3681880))

However, my advice is to stick with the standard UI options that already come with iOS. Don't try to make your app look and behave exactly the same as the Android version. Think about how to repackage it so that it looks and feels like an iOS app. See the following link for some choices.

- [Overview of the standard iOS options for temporarily displaying information to a user.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32295641/3681880)

Consider redesigning the UI in a way that conveys the same information. Or, if the information is very important, then an [Alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022479/how-would-i-create-a-uialertview-in-swift/33340757#33340757) might be the answer.

Comment: Very well put, especially the notion of reworking the UI.  It's definitely not the simplest answer for developers or designers, but Toasts could easily become another mobile UX “junk drawer,” too often used as a dumping ground for content that 1) is chatty and distracting, or 2) is genuinely useful information, and, as such, would be better presented in direct context with the primary content elements of the application as a badge, icon, or inline status message.

Answer (score 47):

**Swift 4**

How about this small trick?

```
func showToast(controller: UIViewController, message : String, seconds: Double) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    alert.view.alpha = 0.6
    alert.view.layer.cornerRadius = 15

    controller.present(alert, animated: true)

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + seconds) {
        alert.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

**Example of calling:**

```
showToast(controller: self, message : "This is a test", seconds: 2.0)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Looks awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sazzad, the problem was obviously, that it requires a NavigationController. I was just trying to bring it up. Maybe my comment is wrong and obsolete

Comment: happy to hear that u fixed

Comment: Thanks a lot, very precise solution

Answer (score 31):

**Swift 3**

For a simple solution without third party code:

[image]

Just use a normal UIAlertController but with style = [actionSheet](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller/style/actionsheet?changes=_4) (look at code down below)

```
let alertDisapperTimeInSeconds = 2.0
let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Toast!", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
self.present(alert, animated: true)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + alertDisapperTimeInSeconds) {
  alert.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

The advantage of this solution:

1. Android like Toast message
2. Still iOS Look&Feel

Comment: Clever one. I would have never thought of this, thanks :D

Comment: Thanks, this is the most simple and elegant solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

For **Swift 3 & 4**:

Use [**Toaster**](https://github.com/devxoul/Toaster) library

```
Toast(text: "Hello, world!", duration: Delay.long)
```

[image]

For **Swift 2**:

Use [JLToast](https://github.com/devxoul/Toaster/tree/1.4.2)

Answer (score 4):

If you want one with iOS Style, download this framework from Github

[iOS Toast Alert View Framework](https://github.com/estampworld/ios-toast-alerts)

This examples work on you UIViewController, once you imported the Framework.

Example 1:

```
//Manual 
let tav = ToastAlertView()
tav.message = "Hey!"
tav.image = UIImage(named: "img1")!
tav.show()
//tav.dismiss() to Hide
```

Example 2:

```
//Toast Alert View with Time Dissmis Only
self.showToastAlert("5 Seconds",
                image: UIImage(named: "img1")!,
                hideWithTap: false,
                hideWithTime: true,
                hideTime: 5.0)
```

Final:

[image: Toast Alert View Image Example]

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4.0:

Make a new swift file . (File-New-File-Empty Swift File). Name it UIViewToast.Add the following Code.

```
import UIKit

func /(lhs: CGFloat, rhs: Int) -> CGFloat {
return lhs / CGFloat(rhs)
}

let HRToastDefaultDuration  =   2.0
let HRToastFadeDuration     =   0.2
let HRToastHorizontalMargin : CGFloat  =   10.0
let HRToastVerticalMargin   : CGFloat  =   10.0

let HRToastPositionDefault  =   "bottom"
let HRToastPositionTop      =   "top"
let HRToastPositionCenter   =   "center"

// activity
let HRToastActivityWidth  :  CGFloat  = 100.0
let HRToastActivityHeight :  CGFloat  = 100.0
let HRToastActivityPositionDefault    = "center"

// image size
let HRToastImageViewWidth :  CGFloat  = 80.0
let HRToastImageViewHeight:  CGFloat  = 80.0

// label setting
let HRToastMaxWidth       :  CGFloat  = 0.8;      // 80% of parent view width
let HRToastMaxHeight      :  CGFloat  = 0.8;
let HRToastFontSize       :  CGFloat  = 16.0
let HRToastMaxTitleLines              = 0
let HRToastMaxMessageLines            = 0

// shadow appearance
let HRToastShadowOpacity  : CGFloat   = 0.8
let HRToastShadowRadius   : CGFloat   = 6.0
let HRToastShadowOffset   : CGSize    = CGSize(width: 4.0, height: 4.0)

let HRToastOpacity        : CGFloat   = 0.5
let HRToastCornerRadius   : CGFloat   = 10.0

var HRToastActivityView: UnsafePointer<UIView>?
var HRToastTimer: UnsafePointer<Timer>?
var HRToastView: UnsafePointer<UIView>?


// Color Scheme
let HRAppColor:UIColor = UIColor.black//UIappViewController().appUIColor
let HRAppColor_2:UIColor = UIColor.white


let HRToastHidesOnTap       =   true
let HRToastDisplayShadow    =   false

//HRToast (UIView + Toast using Swift)

extension UIView {

//public methods
func makeToast(message msg: String) {
    self.makeToast(message: msg, duration: HRToastDefaultDuration, position: HRToastPositionDefault as AnyObject)
}

func makeToast(message msg: String, duration: Double, position: AnyObject) {
    let toast = self.viewForMessage(msg: msg, title: nil, image: nil)
    self.showToast(toast: toast!, duration: duration, position: position)
}

func makeToast(message msg: String, duration: Double, position: AnyObject, title: String) {
    let toast = self.viewForMessage(msg: msg, title: title, image: nil)
    self.showToast(toast: toast!, duration: duration, position: position)
}

func makeToast(message msg: String, duration: Double, position: AnyObject, image: UIImage) {
    let toast = self.viewForMessage(msg: msg, title: nil, image: image)
    self.showToast(toast: toast!, duration: duration, position: position)
}

func makeToast(message msg: String, duration: Double, position: AnyObject, title: String, image: UIImage) {
    let toast = self.viewForMessage(msg: msg, title: title, image: image)
    self.showToast(toast: toast!, duration: duration, position: position)
}

func showToast(toast: UIView) {
    self.showToast(toast: toast, duration: HRToastDefaultDuration, position: HRToastPositionDefault as AnyObject)
}

func showToast(toast: UIView, duration: Double, position: AnyObject) {
    let existToast = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &HRToastView) as! UIView?
    if existToast != nil {
        if let timer: Timer = objc_getAssociatedObject(existToast!, &HRToastTimer) as? Timer {
            timer.invalidate();
        }
        self.hideToast(toast: existToast!, force: false);
    }

    toast.center = self.centerPointForPosition(position: position, toast: toast)
    toast.alpha = 0.0

    if HRToastHidesOnTap {
        let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: toast, action: #selector(handleToastTapped(recognizer:)))
        toast.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
        toast.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
        toast.isExclusiveTouch = true;
    }

    self.addSubview(toast)
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &HRToastView, toast, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: HRToastFadeDuration,
                               delay: 0.0, options: ([.curveEaseOut, .allowUserInteraction]),
                               animations: {
                                toast.alpha = 1.0
    },
                               completion: { (finished: Bool) in
                                let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: duration, target: self, selector: #selector(self.toastTimerDidFinish(timer:)), userInfo: toast, repeats: false)
                                objc_setAssociatedObject(toast, &HRToastTimer, timer, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
    })
}

func makeToastActivity() {
    self.makeToastActivity(position: HRToastActivityPositionDefault as AnyObject)
}

func showToastActivity() {
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    self.makeToastActivity()
}

func removeToastActivity() {
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.hideToastActivity()

}

func makeToastActivityWithMessage(message msg: String){
    self.makeToastActivity(position: HRToastActivityPositionDefault as AnyObject, message: msg)
}
func makeToastActivityWithMessage(message msg: String,addOverlay: Bool){

    self.makeToastActivity(position: HRToastActivityPositionDefault as AnyObject, message: msg,addOverlay: true)
}

func makeToastActivity(position pos: AnyObject, message msg: String = "",addOverlay overlay: Bool = false) {
    let existingActivityView: UIView? = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &HRToastActivityView) as? UIView
    if existingActivityView != nil { return }

    let activityView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height))
    activityView.center = self.centerPointForPosition(position: pos, toast: activityView)
    activityView.alpha = 0.0
    activityView.autoresizingMask = ([.flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleRightMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin])
    activityView.layer.cornerRadius = HRToastCornerRadius

    if HRToastDisplayShadow {
        activityView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        activityView.layer.shadowOpacity = Float(HRToastShadowOpacity)
        activityView.layer.shadowRadius = HRToastShadowRadius
        activityView.layer.shadowOffset = HRToastShadowOffset
    }

    let activityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .whiteLarge)
    activityIndicatorView.center = CGPoint(x:activityView.bounds.size.width / 2, y: activityView.bounds.size.height / 2)
    activityIndicatorView.color = HRAppColor
    activityView.addSubview(activityIndicatorView)
    activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()

    if (!msg.isEmpty){
        activityIndicatorView.frame.origin.y -= 10



        let activityMessageLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: activityView.bounds.origin.x, y: (activityIndicatorView.frame.origin.y + activityIndicatorView.frame.size.height + 10), width: activityView.bounds.size.width, height: 20))
        activityMessageLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        activityMessageLabel.font = (msg.count<=10) ? UIFont(name:activityMessageLabel.font.fontName, size: 16) : UIFont(name:activityMessageLabel.font.fontName, size: 16)
        activityMessageLabel.textAlignment = .center
        activityMessageLabel.text = msg + ".."
        if overlay {
            activityMessageLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
            activityView.backgroundColor = HRAppColor.withAlphaComponent(HRToastOpacity)
            activityIndicatorView.color = UIColor.white
        }
        else {
            activityMessageLabel.textColor = HRAppColor
            activityView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            activityIndicatorView.color = HRAppColor
        }

        activityView.addSubview(activityMessageLabel)

    }

    self.addSubview(activityView)

    // associate activity view with self
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &HRToastActivityView, activityView, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: HRToastFadeDuration,
                               delay: 0.0,
                               options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut,
                               animations: {
                                activityView.alpha = 1.0
    },
                               completion: nil)
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}

func hideToastActivity() {
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let existingActivityView = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &HRToastActivityView) as! UIView?
    if existingActivityView == nil { return }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: HRToastFadeDuration,
                               delay: 0.0,
                               options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut,
                               animations: {
                                existingActivityView!.alpha = 0.0
    },
                               completion: { (finished: Bool) in
                                existingActivityView!.removeFromSuperview()
                                objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &HRToastActivityView, nil, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
    })
}

/*
 *  private methods (helper)
 */
func hideToast(toast: UIView) {
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.hideToast(toast: toast, force: false);
}

func hideToast(toast: UIView, force: Bool) {
    let completeClosure = { (finish: Bool) -> () in
        toast.removeFromSuperview()
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &HRToastTimer, nil, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
    }

    if force {
        completeClosure(true)
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: HRToastFadeDuration,
                                   delay: 0.0,
                                   options: ([.curveEaseIn, .beginFromCurrentState]),
                                   animations: {
                                    toast.alpha = 0.0
        },
                                   completion:completeClosure)
    }
}

@objc func toastTimerDidFinish(timer: Timer) {
    self.hideToast(toast: timer.userInfo as! UIView)
}

@objc func handleToastTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    // var timer = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &HRToastTimer) as! NSTimer
    // timer.invalidate()

    self.hideToast(toast: recognizer.view!)
}

func centerPointForPosition(position: AnyObject, toast: UIView) -> CGPoint {
    if position is String {
        let toastSize = toast.bounds.size
        let viewSize  = self.bounds.size
        if position.lowercased == HRToastPositionTop {
            return CGPoint(x: viewSize.width/2, y: toastSize.height/2 + HRToastVerticalMargin)

        } else if position.lowercased == HRToastPositionDefault {
            return CGPoint(x:viewSize.width/2, y:viewSize.height - toastSize.height - 15 - HRToastVerticalMargin)
        } else if position.lowercased == HRToastPositionCenter {
            return CGPoint(x:viewSize.width/2, y:viewSize.height/2)
        }
    } else if position is NSValue {
        return position.cgPointValue
    }

    print("Warning: Invalid position for toast.")
    return self.centerPointForPosition(position: HRToastPositionDefault as AnyObject, toast: toast)
}

func viewForMessage(msg: String?, title: String?, image: UIImage?) -> UIView? {
    if msg == nil && title == nil && image == nil { return nil }

    var msgLabel: UILabel?
    var titleLabel: UILabel?
    var imageView: UIImageView?

    let wrapperView = UIView()
    wrapperView.autoresizingMask = ([.flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleRightMargin, .flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin])
    wrapperView.layer.cornerRadius = HRToastCornerRadius
    wrapperView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(HRToastOpacity)

    if HRToastDisplayShadow {
        wrapperView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        wrapperView.layer.shadowOpacity = Float(HRToastShadowOpacity)
        wrapperView.layer.shadowRadius = HRToastShadowRadius
        wrapperView.layer.shadowOffset = HRToastShadowOffset
    }

    if image != nil {
        imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView!.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView!.frame = CGRect(x:HRToastHorizontalMargin, y: HRToastVerticalMargin, width: CGFloat(HRToastImageViewWidth), height: CGFloat(HRToastImageViewHeight))
    }

    var imageWidth: CGFloat, imageHeight: CGFloat, imageLeft: CGFloat
    if imageView != nil {
        imageWidth = imageView!.bounds.size.width
        imageHeight = imageView!.bounds.size.height
        imageLeft = HRToastHorizontalMargin
    } else {
        imageWidth  = 0.0; imageHeight = 0.0; imageLeft   = 0.0
    }

    if title != nil {
        titleLabel = UILabel()
        titleLabel!.numberOfLines = HRToastMaxTitleLines
        titleLabel!.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: HRToastFontSize)
        titleLabel!.textAlignment = .center
        titleLabel!.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        titleLabel!.textColor = UIColor.white
        titleLabel!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        titleLabel!.alpha = 1.0
        titleLabel!.text = title

        // size the title label according to the length of the text

        let maxSizeTitle = CGSize(width: (self.bounds.size.width * HRToastMaxWidth) - imageWidth, height: self.bounds.size.height * HRToastMaxHeight)

        let expectedHeight = title!.stringHeightWithFontSize(fontSize: HRToastFontSize, width: maxSizeTitle.width)
        titleLabel!.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: maxSizeTitle.width, height: expectedHeight)
    }

    if msg != nil {
        msgLabel = UILabel();
        msgLabel!.numberOfLines = HRToastMaxMessageLines
        msgLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: HRToastFontSize)
        msgLabel!.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        msgLabel!.textAlignment = .center
        msgLabel!.textColor = UIColor.white
        msgLabel!.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        msgLabel!.alpha = 1.0
        msgLabel!.text = msg


        let maxSizeMessage = CGSize(width: (self.bounds.size.width * HRToastMaxWidth) - imageWidth, height: self.bounds.size.height * HRToastMaxHeight)
        let expectedHeight = msg!.stringHeightWithFontSize(fontSize: HRToastFontSize, width: maxSizeMessage.width)
        msgLabel!.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: maxSizeMessage.width, height: expectedHeight)
    }

    var titleWidth: CGFloat, titleHeight: CGFloat, titleTop: CGFloat, titleLeft: CGFloat
    if titleLabel != nil {
        titleWidth = titleLabel!.bounds.size.width
        titleHeight = titleLabel!.bounds.size.height
        titleTop = HRToastVerticalMargin
        titleLeft = imageLeft + imageWidth + HRToastHorizontalMargin
    } else {
        titleWidth = 0.0; titleHeight = 0.0; titleTop = 0.0; titleLeft = 0.0
    }

    var msgWidth: CGFloat, msgHeight: CGFloat, msgTop: CGFloat, msgLeft: CGFloat
    if msgLabel != nil {
        msgWidth = msgLabel!.bounds.size.width
        msgHeight = msgLabel!.bounds.size.height
        msgTop = titleTop + titleHeight + HRToastVerticalMargin
        msgLeft = imageLeft + imageWidth + HRToastHorizontalMargin
    } else {
        msgWidth = 0.0; msgHeight = 0.0; msgTop = 0.0; msgLeft = 0.0
    }

    let largerWidth = max(titleWidth, msgWidth)
    let largerLeft  = max(titleLeft, msgLeft)

    // set wrapper view's frame
    let wrapperWidth  = max(imageWidth + HRToastHorizontalMargin * 2, largerLeft + largerWidth + HRToastHorizontalMargin)
    let wrapperHeight = max(msgTop + msgHeight + HRToastVerticalMargin, imageHeight + HRToastVerticalMargin * 2)
    wrapperView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: wrapperWidth, height: wrapperHeight)

    // add subviews
    if titleLabel != nil {
        titleLabel!.frame = CGRect(x: titleLeft, y: titleTop, width: titleWidth, height: titleHeight)
        wrapperView.addSubview(titleLabel!)
    }
    if msgLabel != nil {
        msgLabel!.frame = CGRect(x: msgLeft, y: msgTop, width: msgWidth, height: msgHeight)
        wrapperView.addSubview(msgLabel!)
    }
    if imageView != nil {
        wrapperView.addSubview(imageView!)
    }

    return wrapperView
    }

    }

extension String {

func stringHeightWithFontSize(fontSize: CGFloat,width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize)
    let size = CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping;
    let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font:font,
                      NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle:paragraphStyle.copy()]

    let text = self as NSString
    let rect = text.boundingRect(with: size, options:.usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributes, context:nil)
    return rect.size.height
}
}
```

**Usage:**

```
  self.view.makeToast(message: "Simple Toast")
  self.view.makeToast(message: "Simple Toast", duration: 2.0, position:HRToastPositionTop)

  self.view.makeToast(message: "Simple Toast", duration: 2.0, position: HRToastPositionCenter, image: UIImage(named: "ic_120x120")!)

  self.view.makeToast(message: "It is just awesome", duration: 2.0, position: HRToastPositionDefault, title: "Simple Toast")

  self.view.makeToast(message: "It is just awesome", duration: 2.0, position: HRToastPositionCenter, title: "Simple Toast", image: UIImage(named: "ic_120x120")!)

  self.view.makeToastActivity()
  self.view.makeToastActivity(position: HRToastPositionCenter)
  self.view.makeToastActivity(position: HRToastPositionDefault, message: "Loading")
  self.view.makeToastActivityWithMessage(message: "Loading")

  // Hide Toast
  self.view.hideToast(toast: self.view)
  self.view.hideToast(toast: self.view, force: true)
  self.view.hideToastActivity()
```

Comment: too many errors in this code.. changes like .Center to center, whiteColor to white, animateWithDuration to animate(duration, just too many errors.. please fix it..

Answer (score 2):

For the ones that using Xamarin.IOS you can do like this:

```
new UIAlertView(null, message, null, "OK", null).Show();
```

using UIKit; is required.

Answer (score 2):

For me this solution works fine:
https://github.com/cruffenach/CRToast

[image]

Example how use it:

```
    NSDictionary *options = @{
                          kCRToastTextKey : @"Hello World!",
                          kCRToastTextAlignmentKey : @(NSTextAlignmentCenter),
                          kCRToastBackgroundColorKey : [UIColor redColor],
                          kCRToastAnimationInTypeKey : @(CRToastAnimationTypeGravity),
                          kCRToastAnimationOutTypeKey : @(CRToastAnimationTypeGravity),
                          kCRToastAnimationInDirectionKey : @(CRToastAnimationDirectionLeft),
                          kCRToastAnimationOutDirectionKey : @(CRToastAnimationDirectionRight)
                          };
[CRToastManager showNotificationWithOptions:options
                            completionBlock:^{
                                NSLog(@"Completed");
                            }];
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4 syntax for a 3-second delay:

```
present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {                 
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)     
}
```

Comment: Wow. I had this kind of problem where your code gave me idea what to do. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Swift Implementation of Android Toast using Alert which dissipate after 3 secs.

```
    func showAlertView(title: String?, message: String?) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(okAction)
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(3 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        print("Bye. Lovvy")
        alertController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

To Call it simply :

```
self.showAlertView("Message sent...", message: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 2.0 and considering https://stackoverflow.com/a/5079536/6144027

```
                //TOAST
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "This is a Toast.LENGTH_SHORT", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                self!.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(2.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
                dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    alertController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your solution :
Put Below code into your Xcode project and enjoy,

```
- (void)showMessage:(NSString*)message atPoint:(CGPoint)point {
const CGFloat fontSize = 16;

UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:fontSize];
label.text = message;
label.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x07575B);
[label sizeToFit];

label.center = point;

[self.view addSubview:label];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:1 options:0 animations:^{
    label.alpha = 0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    label.hidden = YES;
    [label removeFromSuperview];
}];
}
```

How to use ?

```
[self showMessage:@"Toast in iOS" atPoint:CGPointMake(160, 695)];
```

Answer (score 1):

fully customizable capsule shape toast message with slide in&out animations.

```
extension UIViewController {

func showToast(message : String, fontSize: Int, bgColor: UIColor, textColor: UIColor, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, delayTime: Double) {

    let toastLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width/2 - width/2, y: -10, width: width, height: height))
    toastLabel.backgroundColor = bgColor
    toastLabel.textColor = textColor
    toastLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: CGFloat(fontSize), weight: .bold)
    toastLabel.textAlignment = .center
    toastLabel.text = message
    toastLabel.layer.cornerRadius = height/2
    toastLabel.clipsToBounds  =  true
    self.view.addSubview(toastLabel)
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(toastLabel)
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: TimeInterval(delayTime), options: .curveLinear) {
    toastLabel.center.y += 60
} completion: { (isCompleted) in
    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2.0, repeats: false, block: { _ in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: TimeInterval(delayTime), options: .curveLinear) {
                toastLabel.center.y -= 60
            } completion: { (isCompleted) in
                
            }
         })

}


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Again if using IOS on Xamarin there is a new component called BTProgressHUD in the component store

Answer (score 0):

1) Download **toast-notifications-ios** from [this link](https://github.com/ecstasy2/toast-notifications-ios)

2) go to Targets -> Build Phases and add **-fno-objc-arc** to the "compiler Sources" for relevant files

3) make a function and `#import "iToast.h"`

```
-(void)showToast :(NSString *)strMessage {
    iToast * objiTost = [iToast makeText:strMessage];
    [objiTost setFontSize:11];
    [objiTost setDuration:iToastDurationNormal];
    [objiTost setGravity:iToastGravityBottom];
    [objiTost show];
}
```

4) call where you need to display toast message

```
[self showToast:@"This is example text."];
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought off a simple way to do the toast! using UIAlertController without button! We use the button text as our message! get it?
see below code:

```
func alert(title: String?, message: String?, bdy:String) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: bdy, style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(okAction)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        //print("Bye. Lovvy")
        alertController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) 
    }    
}
```

---

use it like this:

```
self.alert(nil,message:nil,bdy:"Simple Toast!") // toast
self.alert(nil,message:nil,bdy:"Alert") // alert with "Alert" button
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have done in Swift 3.0. I created UIView extension and calling the **self.view.showToast(message: "Message Here", duration: 3.0)** and **self.view.hideToast()**

```
extension UIView{
var showToastTag :Int {return 999}

//Generic Show toast
func showToast(message : String, duration:TimeInterval) {

    let toastLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: (self.frame.size.width)-60, height:64))

    toastLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    toastLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
    toastLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    toastLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    toastLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    toastLabel.textAlignment = .center;
    toastLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 17.0)
    toastLabel.text = message
    toastLabel.center = self.center
    toastLabel.isEnabled = true
    toastLabel.alpha = 0.99
    toastLabel.tag = showToastTag
    toastLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    toastLabel.clipsToBounds  =  true
    self.addSubview(toastLabel)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
        toastLabel.alpha = 0.95
    }, completion: {(isCompleted) in
        toastLabel.removeFromSuperview()
    })
}

//Generic Hide toast
func hideToast(){
    if let view = self.viewWithTag(self.showToastTag){
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want pure swift, we released our internal file. It's pretty simple

https://github.com/gglresearchanddevelopment/ios-toast