# Android toast messages on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Is there any way to show user a message such as toast messages in Android in Swift?

Comment: You can find a solution to your problem by just googling it - there are several libraries out there, just choose one.

Comment: ie this one: https://github.com/devxoul/JLToast

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24893788/android-toast-equivalent-in-ios

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this [Toast-Swift](https://github.com/Rannie/Toast-Swift). An easy one!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways.

But this is  easy way for me

http://www.theappguruz.com/tutorial/implement-toast-message-ios-using-swift/